# Writing GZIP file with nio

Tags: java, io, gzip, nio

This is my code:

```
WritableByteChannel channel = null;
GZIPOutputStream out = null;
try {
     channel = Channels.newChannel(new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\111.zip"));

     out = new GZIPOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(channel));
    for (long i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {    
       out.write(("string" + i + "\n").getBytes());
     } 

   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (channel != null) {
                channel.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }    }
```

I get zip but it's contents is damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you saving it as zip if you're using a gzip stream? Use `.gz` as the extension.

**Edit**
Assuming that it's not the .zip extension at fault here (it's still bad though):

1. You should probably consider calling `out.finish()` before closing it.
2. I'm pretty sure you don't need all the channel stuff. You can simply pass the FileOutputStream to GZIPOutputStream

Comment: I want to use nio to improve performance but finish wroked!!! I am runing the test for a huge file now...

Comment: aother question: how to set name for zipped file? right now it has the same name of the zip but without extension.

Comment: @omrid where does it say that NIO will significantly improve the performance? Have you measured it? Do you have a performance problem?

Comment: @EJP NIO won't significantly improve performance in this case, because it's GZIP that does the actual hard work.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Exactly my point. The overhead lies elsewhere.

Comment: At best the use of NIO is a wash here. At worst, it will actually slow it down. The problem is that when you mix IO (GZipOutputStream) with NIO (WritableByteChannel), you have simply created an additional layer of translation (from byte[] to ByteBuffer) and method calls (OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) call through to WritableByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer)).

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\111.gz"));
WritableByteChannel out = Channels.newChannel(gzipOS);
```

And simply use `out.write()` to write using NIO. Don't forget to close resources later.

Comment: out.write requires ByteBuffer

Comment: anyway out.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(("string" + "\n").getBytes())); same result damaged file

Comment: Yes, you will need `ByteBuffer`. And what you do mean by damaged file?

Comment: well, the zip file has size bu the file inside has size of 0. when i try to view it with some 3rd party software i get error

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't `flush()` and `close()` `gzipOS`. That's only when the data is written out.

Answer (score 1):

When you call out.close() it will close the underlying stream/channel as well.

If you close the underlying channel first any buffered data or footer cannot be written.

The GZIP format contains a CRC32 which must be at the end, cannot be written until you clsoe the stream and I expect this is missing so the file contents cannot be validated. The simplest solution is to not close the underlying channel yourself.

BTW: As a rule it is usually best to close resources in the reverse order they were created. ;)